# Why am I only getting NULL back?

Tags: java

All I am getting back when I run the program is null...and I can't stare at this anymore. I just can't seem to find the error... Could someone just give a hint please... I don't know what other details are relevant.

```
 public class Deckofcards
   {
      public static final int NCARDS = 52;

      private card[] deckOfCards;         // Contains all 52 cards
      private int currentCard;            // deal THIS card in deck           

      public Deckofcards( )    // Constructor
      {
     deckOfCards = new card[ NCARDS ];

     int i = 0;

     for ( int suit = card.SPADE; suit <= card.DIAMOND; suit++ )
        for ( int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++ )
        deckOfCards[i++] = new card(suit, rank);

      private byte cardSuit;
      private byte cardRank;

      public card( int suit, int rank )
      {
     if ( rank == 1 )
        cardRank = 14;     // Give Ace the rank 14
     else
        cardRank = (byte) rank;

     cardSuit = (byte) suit;
      }

      public boolean equals( card x )
      {
     if ( this.cardSuit == x.cardSuit &&
          this.cardRank == x.cardRank    )
        return ( true ); 
     else         
        return ( false );
      }

      public String toString()
      {
     return ( Rank[ cardRank ] + Suit[ cardSuit ] );
      }
   }


    public class Dealer

   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {

     Deckofcards a;

     a = new Deckofcards();
     System.out.println(a);      // What a new deck look like     

     System.out.println("Shuffle cards....");            
     a.shuffle(1000);            // Shuffle deck of card "a"
     System.out.println(a);      // Deck after shuffling

     card b;

     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);

      }
   }    
     currentCard = 0;
      }

       //shuffle(n): shuffle the deck

      public void shuffle(int n)
      {
     int i, j, k;

     for ( k = 0; k < n; k++ )
     {
         i = (int) ( NCARDS * Math.random() );  // Pick 2 random cards
         j = (int) ( NCARDS * Math.random() );  // in the deck

        //swap these randomly picked cards

         card tmp = deckOfCards[i];
         deckOfCards[i] = deckOfCards[j];
         deckOfCards[j] = tmp;;
     }

     currentCard = 0;   // Reset current card to deal
      }

     //deal(): deal deckOfCards[currentCard] out

      public card deal()
      {
     if ( currentCard < NCARDS )
     {
        return ( deckOfCards[ currentCard++ ] );
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println("Out of cards error");
        return ( null );  // Error;
     }
      }

      public String toString()
      {
     String s = "";
     int k;

     k = 0;
     for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
     {
        for ( int j = 1; j <= 13; j++ )
        s += (deckOfCards[k++] + " ");

        s += "\n";
     }
     return ( s );
      }
   }


    public class card
   {
      public static final int SPADE   = 4;
      public static final int HEART   = 3;
      public static final int CLUB    = 2;
      public static final int DIAMOND = 1;

      private static final String[] Suit = { "*", "d", "c", "h", "s"};
      private static final String[] Rank = { "*", "1", "2", "3", "4",
               "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};

      private byte cardSuit;
      private byte cardRank;

      public card( int suit, int rank )
      {
     if ( rank == 1 )
        cardRank = 14;     // Give Ace the rank 14
     else
        cardRank = (byte) rank;

     cardSuit = (byte) suit;
      }

      public boolean equals( card x )
      {
     if ( this.cardSuit == x.cardSuit &&
          this.cardRank == x.cardRank    )
        return ( true ); 
     else         
        return ( false );
      }

      public String toString()
      {
     return ( Rank[ cardRank ] + Suit[ cardSuit ] );
      }
   }


    public class Dealer

   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {

     Deckofcards a;

     a = new Deckofcards();
     System.out.println(a);      // What a new deck look like     

     System.out.println("Shuffle cards....");            
     a.shuffle(1000);            // Shuffle deck of card "a"
     System.out.println(a);      // Deck after shuffling

     card b;

     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);
     b = a.deal();
     System.out.println("Deal a card: " + b);

      }
   }
```

Here is what I am receiving.

```
null null null null null null null null null null null null null
```

null null null null null null null null null null null null null 
null null null null null null null null null null null null null 
null null null null null null null null null null null null null

Shuffle cards....
null null null null null null null null null null null null null 
null null null null null null null null null null null null null 
null null null null null null null null null null null null null 
null null null null null null null null null null null null null

Deal a card: null
Deal a card: null
Deal a card: null
Deal a card: null
Deal a card: null

Comment: So you expect us to read through 200 lines of code to find a `null` somewhere...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include which method(s) is(are) returning null, and **please fix your code indentation**.

Comment: They are all returning null. I will post what my results look like.

Comment: I don't expect anything. Just if someone could help...not sure why I am getting all nulls....

Comment: I recommend you step through your code using a debugger like Eclipse or IntelliJ where you can go line by line and see what code is returning the null, and is in your execution code path

Comment: I am using eclipse and its not giving me an exception its returning values...Just not sure why they are all null

Comment: I guess `return ( Rank[ cardRank ] + Suit[ cardSuit ] );` needs to be `return ( Rank[ this.cardRank ] + Suit[ this.cardSuit ] );` in class card, method toString.

Comment: Using `private` for local variables seems illegal. At least you should require compilable code to get something printed. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try inserting `System.out.println()` statements before the `return` statements to see where `null` is erroneously being returned. I'd also advise using `System.out.println()` statements after initializing objects as well to ensure they have properly been initialized and are not null.

Comment: inserting statements before an after printed fine. I believe my return values are the ones coming back as null as it prints "Shuffle Cards...." and " Deal a Card" just fine.

Comment: MikeCAT I posted an example of my console results at the end of my post

Comment: also adjusting my return (Rank [ this.cardRank ] + Suit [ this.cardSuit ] );                          didn;t work

Answer (score -1):

FOUND MY ERROR....

In my Deck of cards.java file...diamond and Spade were in the incorrect places....below is the corrected portion.

```
for ( int suit = card.DIAMOND; suit <= card.SPADE; suit++ )
        for ( int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++ )
        deckOfCards[i++] = new card(suit, rank);
```